# checking for specific error code in PL/SQL exception block

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting the ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value error in a pl/sql trigger code. I actualy want to do some specific exception handling only if this error occurs else do the regular exception handling in my code.
My question is how do I capture the specific ORA codes in exception blocks. Like If I want to add a if condition like

```
If(oracode = something) then ...
else ...
```

the SQLERRM gives the ora code with error message. how do I use this in IF condition ?

Need help with this

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for SQLCODE - these are negative numbers when there is an error.

```
if SQLCODE = -6503 then  ....
```